# Storing loop values into variable and use it outside of it

Tags: c#, razor, foreach

I'm trying to understand how to store data from a loop in a variable and use it outside.

As a code example, i have a string in a variable declared outside the foreach loop which is an array created by the Split method:

```
var features = @GetString(fieldValue);
List<string> optionValues = new List<string>();

foreach(var option in customField.Options)
{
   optionValues.Add(option.customField.Options.Name);
}             

features = string.Join(';', optionValues);

foreach(var str in features.Split(';'))
{
    features = str;
}
```

I want to render the string features in a helper function outside of it like this:

```
@RenderFieldValue(features)
```

The helper receives a string parameter:

```
@helper RenderFieldValue(string value)
{
    <div>@value</div>
}
```

The problem is that i'm only outputting "part4" which is the last part of the string. I'm trying to understand how programming works in relation to storing values from a loop and use all of them outside of it.
It should output this:

```
part1
part2
part3
part4
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I've changed my code to exemplify why i cannot use the helper inside the loop. The features variable may come with different values and i only want it to split when it has semicolons

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here is that you store your new strings into the **same string** you had at the begining. (Btw the code you showed us can't compile)

You have your string `features`, you iterate through the split in your `foreach`, then for each split result you **replace** `features` by the **result**. Which means, at the last iteration of your `foreach` the last split result will become your new `features` ("" in this case and not "part4" since you have another ";" at the end).

So now what you can do is, directly call `@RenderFieldValue()` in your foreach with `str` as a parameter or change `@RenderFieldValue()` behavior as follows :

```
@helper RenderFieldValue(string value)
{
    @foreach (String s in value.Split(';'))
    {
        <div>@s</div>
    }
}
```

Where `value` is your string `features`.

**EDIT**

Here is a some code showing you how **scope** works :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Scope scope = new Scope();

        String works = scope.canBeAccessedOutside;
        String wontWork = scope.cannotBeAccessedOutside; // Compile error.
        String stillWontWork = scope.cannotBeAccessedOutsideThisMethod; // Compile error.

        scope.MethodCanBeAccessedOutside();
        scope.MethodCannotBeAccessedOutside(); // Compile error.
    }
}

class Scope
{
    // Since it is declared inside the class scope, you can use it anywhere in the class, and outside since it is public.
    public String canBeAccessedOutside;

    // Since it is declared inside the class scope, you can use it anywhere in the class, but not outside since it is private.
    private String cannotBeAccessedOutside; 

    // Can be used inside and outside the class.
    public void MethodCanBeAccessedOutside()
    {
        // Can only be used inside this method.
        String cannotBeAccessedOutsideThisMethod;

        MethodCannotBeAccessedOutside(); // Compile since this is in the same class.
    }

    // Can only be used inside this class.
    private void MethodCannotBeAccessedOutside()
    {
        String doesntWork = cannotBeAccessedOutsideThisMethod; // Compile error. 

        String work = cannotBeAccessedOutside;
    }
}
```

In order to clarify, **loop scope** works like a **method scope** or a **class scope**, appart from the public and private keywords since loops can only be created inside a method. You can use variables that are accessible from outside of your loop scope (like `feature` in your exemple) or create new ones that are only accessible inside your loop scope. But **don't modify** the same variable you are using to iterate !

Hope this helps !

Comment: Oh right...thanks for explaining why the variable will always be overwritten inside the loop on each iteration. I do understand scope but in this case the helper needs to be rendered outside the loop i showed because it is under if conditions. Besides, the features variable can be of different values...i only want it to split when it has semicolons. I've changed my code to explain it better

Comment: I edited your post, the thing is, if you want to split your `features` string and display each split in a div, you must go with a loop. In the sample of code I gave you, the Render is **outside** the loop. You give him your `features` containing `part1;part2;part3;part4`, but you have a loop **inside** your render, this means that when you will call your Render, it will take your string, iterate through it and print a div with each split, You don't need to split your `features` string before hand, you can do it when you need to display it inside your Render.